# passing error message from service to controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

**Controller.js**

```
var vm = this;
vm.admin = {};

vm.add = function () {
    API.addAdmin(token, vm.admin)
        .then(function (resp) {
            vm.hideForm = true;
            vm.showButton = true;
            Notify.green(resp);
        }, function (resp) {
            Notify.red(resp);
        });
};
```

**API.js**

```
function addAdmin(token, dataObj) {
        return Constant.getApiUrl()
            .then(function (url) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: url + '/client/admin',
                    headers: {
                        'Token': token
                    },
                    data: dataObj
                }).then(handleResp);

                function handleResp(resp) {
                    var responseStatus = (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) ? 'good' : 'bad';
                    if (responseStatus === 'good') {
                        console.log("Success" + resp);
                        return resp;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Failed" + resp);
                        return resp;
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

1. If I get a success response in API then i need to connect it to success function in my controller and if i get error message in my API, then i need it to connect it to error function in my controller.How should I evaluate the response status from my API(is either success or error).
2. I don't want to pass successfn, errorfn from my controller to API(only if there's no alternative).
3. I need to get the response data from API to controller to show it in Notify message.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In service (assign response values in "*originalData*"):

```
angular.module('appname').service('myserviceName', function(yourExistingService){
          this.myFunction= function(originalData) {
         //for next line to work return promise from your addAdmin method.
          var promise =  yourExistingService.getResponseFromURL(originalData);
                           return promise;
             }                         
         });
```

And in your controller  :

```
var promise = myserviceName.myFunction($scope.originalData);
              promise.$promise.then(function() {
                         console.log($scope.originalData);                                 
                     });
```

And then you can check you "*originalData*" and write code according to your need.For more detail you can have a look on this http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html.

Comment: Hi @Amit, the functionality is same as mine, I need to differentiate either success or failure **in the promise** it returns from service to Controller, thanks